# Beego how to access params submitted with multipart/form-data header?

Tags: curl, go, multipartform-data, beego

I've ran into a problem as follows:
When I make a `curl` request to my `beego` app

> curl http://localhost:8080/controller/path  -X POST -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; charset=UTF-8' -F “file=@file.csv;filename=file.csv” -F “name=first”

I want to access `name` param from my controller, but when I try

> func (c *Controller) Path() {
>   ...
>   var name string
>   c.Ctx.Input.Bind(&name, "name")
>   // or I've tried 'name := c.GetString("name")'
>   ...
>   }

result  is always an empty string as `name` variable.

What am I doing wrong ? How can I access params in this case ?  Please any advice welcome !

**Update 1**
I've tried `Parse to struct`  approach, with no luck...

```
type   DataParams struct {
  Name string `form:"name"`
}

    cLDP := DataParams{}
    if err := c.ParseForm(&cLDP); err != nil {
        return ret, err
    }
```

***Update 2***
as of comment, I've tried

```
c.Ctx.Input.ParseFormOrMulitForm(99999)
var name string
c.Ctx.Input.Bind(&name, "name")
```

***Update 3***
after trying altogether I'm lost...

```
name := c.Ctx.Input.Query("name")
params := c.Ctx.Input.Params()
name2 := c.GetString("name")
c.Ctx.Input.ParseFormOrMulitForm(99999)
params2 := c.Ctx.Input.Params()
fmt.Println("Debug 2->", name)
fmt.Println("Debug 5->", name2)
fmt.Println("Debug 3->", params)
fmt.Println("Debug 4->", params2)
```

output is

```
Debug 2->
Debug 3-> map[...]
Debug 4-> map[...]
Debug 5->
```

no name param detected

***Update 4***
if I use `c.Ctx.Input.RequestBody` it not surprisingly is empty

And still no luck :(

Comment: Before calling `Bind` try calling the [ParseFormOrMulitForm](https://godoc.org/github.com/astaxie/beego/context#BeegoInput.ParseFormOrMulitForm) method on input. Please note the Mu**li**t typo is not mine, that's how the method is defined.

Comment: No luck, please see updates

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to access the `name` parameter value using the [Query](https://godoc.org/github.com/astaxie/beego/context#BeegoInput.Query) method, like so:

```
name := c.Ctx.Input.Query("name")
```

If you want to use `Bind` you can do something like this:

```
names := []string{}
if err := c.Ctx.Input.Bind(&names, "name"); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
log.Println(name[0]) // first
```

But you'll also have to update your `curl` to specifically declare the `name` parameter as an array with index:

```
curl ... -F "name[0]=first"
```

This is because internally Go stores a form's parameter values in a slice of strings (see [url.Values](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#Values)) and beego is using this as well, so after beego parses the form it will look like this `url.Values{"name": []string{"first"}}` and so beego does not know how to bind `[]string{"first"}` into a plain `string`.

Answer (score 1):

change the "Content-Type: multipart/form-data to enctype:multipart/form-data